# How to set tooltip on NSPathComponentCell?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, tooltip

I am using Cocoa's NSPathControl and I would like to display a tooltip on hover of any of the path cells.

NSPathComponentCell doesn't seem to have any implementation for tooltip by default.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked something up, that will do the job for now. I am subclassing NSPathControl, NSPathCell and NSPathComponentCell.

Here is the code:

```c
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface BreadcrumbView : NSPathControl

@end
```

```c
#import "BreadcrumbView.h"
#import "BreadcrumbCell.h"
#import "BreadcrumbComponentCell.h"

static BOOL isInitialized = NO;

@implementation BreadcrumbView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if ( !isInitialized ) {
        isInitialized = YES;
        [self.cell addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"toolTip" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
    }
    // Drawing code here.
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"toolTip"] ) {
        [self setToolTip: ((BreadcrumbCell*)object).toolTip];
    }
}

+ (Class)cellClass {
    return [BreadcrumbCell class];
}

@end
```

```c
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "BreadcrumbComponentCell.h"

@interface BreadcrumbCell : NSPathCell

@property NSString* toolTip;

- (BreadcrumbComponentCell*) getHoveredComponentCell;

@end
```

```c
#import "BreadcrumbCell.h"
#import "BreadcrumbComponentCell.h"

@implementation BreadcrumbCell

- (BreadcrumbComponentCell*) getHoveredComponentCell {
    return (BreadcrumbComponentCell*)[self valueForKey:@"_hoveredCell"];
}

- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)view{
    BreadcrumbComponentCell* componentCell = [self getHoveredComponentCell];
    if ( componentCell ) {
        self.toolTip = [componentCell getToolTip];
    }
}

+ (Class)pathComponentCellClass {
    return [BreadcrumbComponentCell class];
}

@end
```

```c
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface BreadcrumbComponentCell : NSPathComponentCell {
    NSString* tooltip;
}

- (void) setToolTip:(NSString*) text;
- (NSString*) getToolTip;

@end
```

```c
#import "BreadcrumbComponentCell.h"

@implementation BreadcrumbComponentCell

- (void) setToolTip:(NSString*) text {
    tooltip = text;
}

- (NSString*) getToolTip{
    return tooltip;
}

@end
```

I hope this will save someone the time I spent looking for it.